# Parse Security Implementation(Currency)

Tags: android, security, parse-platform

I'm building an app that's using virtual currency. I see a problem where if hypothetically speaking since api keys are in plain text,if someone decides to make an app using my keys they can use a simple query like this.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("username","Username");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallBack<ParseUser>(){
    @Override
    public void done(List < ParseUser > parseList, ParseException e) {
        for(ParseUser user: parseList){
            user.set("coins",10000);
            user.saveInBackground();
        }
    }
});
```

This query allows a user to change their currency without being logged in. How can I improve the security of a virtual currency app using Parse? "coins" is a column in the user's row displaying the amount of currency they have. I have a friends list based on relations.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to read [Security](https://parse.com/docs/data#security) and [Implementing Business Logic in Cloud Code](https://parse.com/docs/data#security-cloudcode)

> ### Connection Between Client and Server
>
> When an app first connects to Parse, it identifies itself with an
>   Application ID and a Client key (or REST Key, or .NET Key, or
>   JavaScript Key, depending on which platform you're using). These are
>   not secret and by themselves they do not secure an app. These keys are
>   shipped as a part of your app, and anyone can decompile your app or
>   proxy network traffic from their device to find your client key. This
>   exploit is even easier with JavaScript — one can simply "view source"
>   in the browser and immediately find your client key.
>
> This is why Parse has many other security features to help you secure
>   your data. The client key is given out to your users, so anything that
>   can be done with just the client key is doable by the general public,
>   even malicious hackers.
>
> The master key, on the other hand, is definitely a security mechanism.
>   Using the master key allows you to bypass all of your app's security
>   mechanisms, such as class-level permissions and ACLs. Having the
>   master key is like having root access to your app's servers, and you
>   should guard your master key with the same zeal with which you would
>   guard your production machines' root password.
>
> The overall philosophy is to limit the power of your clients (using
>   client keys), and to perform any sensitive actions requiring the
>   master key in Cloud Code. You'll learn how to best wield this power in
>   the section titled Implementing Business Logic in Cloud Code.

Main idea is next: `coins data would be only readable from client side`.